# removing shades from surface plot in python

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib

When I run the attached python code (some of it is junk that is left over from the figure I try to generate), I get a surface with two shades. (dark and light red), is there a way to turn this into a single shade?

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
from math import sqrt,exp,log, sin
from pylab import rcParams

rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 30,26
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(211, projection='3d')

l = 7
sigma = 1.0/277.450924284104 #You are stupid so have found the charge density for surface potentail of exactly 62mV
pi = 3.14159
b = 1.0/(2*pi*sigma*l)
lambdaD = 9.5

X0, Y0 = np.mgrid[0:1:100j, 0:1:100j]
Z0 = np.zeros_like(X0)
for i in range(0,len(X0)):
    for j in range (0, len(X0[i])):
        Z0[i][j] = 10*sin(X0[i][j]*2*pi)


ax.plot_surface(X0,Y0,Z0,color='red', linewidth=0, rstride=10, cstride=10, antialiased=False)
ax.set_axis_off()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just specify `shade=False` to `ax.plot_surface`.

Also, there's absolutely no need to use nested for loops or to specify the figure size through `rcParams`.

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30, 26))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

X0, Y0 = np.mgrid[0:1:100j, 0:1:100j]
Z0 = 10 * np.sin(X0 * 2 * np.pi)


ax.plot_surface(X0,Y0,Z0,color='red', linewidth=0, rstride=10, cstride=10, 
                antialiased=False, shade=False)
ax.set_axis_off()

plt.show()
```

[image]